# Different types of Structure Declaration in C

Tags: c, structure

I discovered that we can define structures in C in different ways, now I am a little confused with the declaration of structures.

```
//0th way
struct struct0;

//1st Way
struct struct1{
    int m;
};

//2nd Way
struct struct2{
    int m;
}struct2;

//3rd Way
typedef struct{
    int m;
} struct3;

//4th way
typedef struct struct4{
    int m;
} struct4;
```

Comment: The first one doesn't define anything, it **declares** that a structure by that name is defined somewhere else.

Comment: Note that your 2nd way declares a _variable_ called `struct2` of type `struct struct2`.

Comment: `struct struct2{
    int m;
}struct2;` is equivalent to `struct struct2{
    int m;
}; struct struct2 struct2;`

Comment: @KamilCuk OK I get it now.